# Translating "wait until" or "wait for"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, tiempos-verbales

How do you translate phrases involving `wait until` or `wait for`:

> Wait until I call you before you leave for the restaurant.
>
> Wait for me to come home before you buy the tickets.
>
> You should wait until those shirts go on sale.
>
> I waited for him to come but he never showed up.

And what verb tenses should be used in these phrases?

Answer (score 4):

> Wait until I call you before you leave for the restaurant.

*Espera a* que te llame antes de que salgas hacia el restaurante.

> Wait for me to come home before you buy the tickets.

*Esperame a que* llegue a casa antes de comprar los billetes.

> You should wait until those shirts go on sale.

Deberías *esperar a* que esas camisetas salgan a la venta.

> I waited for him to come but he never showed up.

*Esperé a que* viniera pero no apareció.

Comment: +1 but I would translate "Wait for me to come home..." simply as "Espera a que (yo) llegue a casa...". "Espérame a que llegue..." sounds weird to me.